# Pandas GroupBy Sum and Plot - Can it be done simultaneously?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that stores details of diskdrive_nbr, accountName, Size.  accountName values show up multiple times since more than one diskdrive can belong to an account.  I want to sum the disksizes for each account and plot them on a bar graph.  I have this code that seems to do the sum:

```
df.groupby(['accountName'])[['Size [GiB]']].sum()
```

But when I try to plot using the same columns I get error:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df.plot(df['accountName'], kind='bar', legend=None)
```

throws error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['Acct1', 'Acct1', 'Acct1',\n       'Acct4', ',\n       ...\n    'Acct5'],\n      dtype='object', length=57769)] are in the [columns]"
```

Do I have to take the results of df.groupby().sum() put it into a new df then plot?

Comment: `df.groupby(['accountName'])[['Size [GiB]']].sum().plot.bar()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a bar plot with account names on the X axis:

```
df.groupby(['accountName'])[['Size [GiB]']].sum().plot(kind='bar')
```